# Problems with the gold badges or for the correct computation

Tags: discussion, support, badges

I have seen yesterday and today that there is a problem with my gold badges. Now I have this

[image]

and yesterday I had this:

[image]

I'm not interesting for the medals but is there someone that have the same my problem and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is part of an update to the review queues. You now get one Steward badge for every 1,000 reviews in a single queue. For more details, see [Steward badge can now be awarded multiple times -- backfill details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360279/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Very kind  Glorfindel my question is very simple. I do not want anything more than what I am awarded and in addition I am not interested in points and medals. I just like to increase my knowledges and I thank you all users for your cooperation.

Comment: Same here, I just want to share my knowledge about Stack Exchange :)